# How to count the total of items in a json(map) list

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, dart

I have this json in flutter where it contains two list(items) of maps which in turn carry other lists(data). I want to get the sum of the inner list(data) for each combined together. I expect the total to be 3 since the data inside the first list (items) is two + the next contains 1. How can I do that?

```
{
 
data:[
   "items": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": 874,
                        "user_id": 5,
                        "session_id": null,
                        "merchant_id": 7922,
                        "inventory_id": 701,
                        "product_id": 49405,
                        "batch_number": "767819153",
                        "quantity": 2,
                        "unit_price": 1399,
                        "total_price": 2798,
                        "status_id": 4,
                        "created_at": "2023-02-14T07:02:40.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2023-02-14T09:52:27.000000Z",
                        "deleted_at": null,
                        "taxes": [],
                        "tax_amount": 0,
                        "discounts": null,
                        "discount_amount": 0,
                        "is_out_of_stock": false,
                        "is_expired": false,
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 874,
                        "user_id": 5,
                        "session_id": null,
                        "merchant_id": 7922,
                        "inventory_id": 701,
                        "product_id": 49405,
                        "batch_number": "767819153",
                        "quantity": 2,
                        "unit_price": 1399,
                        "total_price": 2798,
                        "status_id": 4,
                        "created_at": "2023-02-14T07:02:40.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2023-02-14T09:52:27.000000Z",
                        "deleted_at": null,
                        "taxes": [],
                        "tax_amount": 0,
                        "discounts": null,
                        "discount_amount": 0,
                        "is_out_of_stock": false,
                        "is_expired": false,
                    }
                ],
                "sub_total": 2798,
                "total_tax": 0,
                "total_discount": 0,
                "total_cost": 2798
            },
     "items": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": 874,
                        "user_id": 5,
                        "session_id": null,
                        "merchant_id": 7922,
                        "inventory_id": 701,
                        "product_id": 49405,
                        "batch_number": "767819153",
                        "quantity": 2,
                        "unit_price": 1399,
                        "total_price": 2798,
                        "status_id": 4,
                        "created_at": "2023-02-14T07:02:40.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2023-02-14T09:52:27.000000Z",
                        "deleted_at": null,
                        "taxes": [],
                        "tax_amount": 0,
                        "discounts": null,
                        "discount_amount": 0,
                        "is_out_of_stock": false,
                        "is_expired": false,
                    }
                ],
                "sub_total": 2798,
                "total_tax": 0,
                "total_discount": 0,
                "total_cost": 2798
            }
   ]
}
```

I have tried looping like this but can't get it.

```
for (var data in responseData['data']) {
          return data['items']['data'];
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the below. Please note the content was changed to be valid Dart object (the area between `data` and `items`, to add a curly bracket).

The main point is: whenever a property is known to be a list, cast it with `as List` and then iterate over its children.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  var total = 0;
  var string = jsonEncode(object);
  var json = jsonDecode(string);
  var data = json['data'] as List;
  for (var i in data) {
    var items = i['items'];
    var innerData = items['data'] as List;
    total += innerData.length;
  }
  print('Total $total');
}

var object = {
  "data": [
    {
      "items": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": 874,
            "user_id": 5,
            "session_id": null,
            "merchant_id": 7922,
            "inventory_id": 701,
            "product_id": 49405,
            "batch_number": "767819153",
            "quantity": 2,
            "unit_price": 1399,
            "total_price": 2798,
            "status_id": 4,
            "created_at": "2023-02-14T07:02:40.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-02-14T09:52:27.000000Z",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "taxes": [],
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "discounts": null,
            "discount_amount": 0,
            "is_out_of_stock": false,
            "is_expired": false,
          },
          {
            "id": 874,
            "user_id": 5,
            "session_id": null,
            "merchant_id": 7922,
            "inventory_id": 701,
            "product_id": 49405,
            "batch_number": "767819153",
            "quantity": 2,
            "unit_price": 1399,
            "total_price": 2798,
            "status_id": 4,
            "created_at": "2023-02-14T07:02:40.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-02-14T09:52:27.000000Z",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "taxes": [],
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "discounts": null,
            "discount_amount": 0,
            "is_out_of_stock": false,
            "is_expired": false,
          }
        ],
        "sub_total": 2798,
        "total_tax": 0,
        "total_discount": 0,
        "total_cost": 2798
      },
    },
    {
      "items": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": 874,
            "user_id": 5,
            "session_id": null,
            "merchant_id": 7922,
            "inventory_id": 701,
            "product_id": 49405,
            "batch_number": "767819153",
            "quantity": 2,
            "unit_price": 1399,
            "total_price": 2798,
            "status_id": 4,
            "created_at": "2023-02-14T07:02:40.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-02-14T09:52:27.000000Z",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "taxes": [],
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "discounts": null,
            "discount_amount": 0,
            "is_out_of_stock": false,
            "is_expired": false,
          }
        ],
        "sub_total": 2798,
        "total_tax": 0,
        "total_discount": 0,
        "total_cost": 2798
      }
    }
  ]
};
```